# psycopg2, inserting timestamp without time zone

Tags: python, postgresql

I am having an issue inserting data into a table in postgresql using psycopg2.

The script does the following:

1. Queries out data from a postgres datebase
2. Does some math using numpy
3. And then I would like to re-insert the date to another table in the database. Here is the code to insert the data:

   ```
   cur.executemany("INSERT INTO water_level_elev (hole_name,measure_date,water_level_elev,rid) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s);",[(hole.tolist(),m_date.tolist(),wl.tolist(),rid.tolist(),)])
   ```

The script throws the following error:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "measure_date" is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type timestamp without time zone[]

LINE 1: INSERT INTO water_level_elev (hole_name,measure_date,water_l...
                                            ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

I'm confused...  The column "measure_date" and the data I'm trying to insert are of the same type.  What's the issue?????

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try it without the `tolist()` on `m_date`.

It's not really possible to answer this completely without seeing the table schema for your `water_level_elev` table, or the source of the `tolist` method. However, it sounds like PostgreSQL is expecting a `measure_date` value that is a timestamp, but is getting a *list* of timestamps. That is why PostgreSQL has `[]` on the end of the second type in the error message. This appears to be because the code you paste calls a method named `tolist` on whatever is in your `m_date` variable, which most likely converts a single timestamp to a list of timestamps, containing the timestamp in `m_date`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am using the "executemany" statement on the insert statement, so I should be able to pass a list/tuple. I think it would have errored on the hole_name column if this was the issue.  I am using the .tolist to convert from a numpy array to a python datatype.  Perhaps I have the syntax for the executemany statement incorrect??? I have tried to pass both a list and a tuple to the statement as well.

Comment: The documentation for numpy's `tolist` says it converts a numpy object into a list. So if `m_date` contains a numpy array of python datetimes, then the result of `m_date.tolist()` is a list of python datetimes, not a single datetime. And yes, `executemany` takes a list of tuples. But you are passing a list of tuples of lists by calling `tolist` on all these things.

Comment: In essence, you are passing something like this to `executemany`: `[([hole, hole, hole], [date, date, date], [wl, wl, wl], [rid, rid, rid],)]`, but instead you want to pass something like this: `[(hole, date, wl, rid), (hole, date, wl, rid), (hole, date, wl, rid)]`. Stare at those until you see the difference; you won't be able to solve this until you understand that.